# Create index if it does not exist

Tags: c++, mysql

I know this question was asked before, but unfortunately I can't run that solution.

I am trying to execute following query on mySQL:

```
IF( SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.statistics WHERE index_name='abcattbl_tnam_ownr' AND table_name='abcattbl') <= 0 CREATE INDEX abcattbl_tnam_ownr ON abcattbl(abt_tnam ASC, abt_ownr ASC);
```

Both mySQL WB and unixODBC isql gives an error. WB indicates that the error is in the IF command/statement.

And of course trying to execute this statement in my C/C++ also fails. That's why I tried WB and isql.

I don't really need the WB/isql execution - I want it to be ran inside my C/C++ program.

What am I missing?

TIA!

Comment: You can't run sql queries directly from C++ programs. At least you need a driver to communicate in between C++ program and MySQL DB

Comment: @Steephen, correct I'm using unixODBC and the latest myODBC driver. Do you want to see some code? It is pretty straightforward - allocate the handles and call SQLExecute().

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I will be using:

```
SELECT( IF( ( SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.statistics WHERE index_name=\'abcattbl_tnam_ownr\' AND table_name=\'abcattbl\' ) > 0, \"SELECT 0\", \"CREATE INDEX abcattbl_tnam_ownr ON abcattbl(abt_tnam ASC, abt_ownr ASC)\"));
```

This query works fine inside WB and from my software.

Thank you.